# Usando MAC, no consigo ejecutar python3 con sublime REPL ¿como puedo hacer correr python3 en sublimeREPL?

Tags: python-3.x

Hola estoy empezando a programar en python,
No consigo correr Python3 con sublimeREPL, después de ejecutar (import sys...)mediante ctrl+alt+B, la ventana nueva que se abre me indica que está ejecutando la version 2.7.16
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leyendo varios post, cree un nuevo Built system, y en el Main.sublime-menu, lo sustituí por un código que encontré en uno de esos post.

Siguiendo todos los pasos, me sigue ejecutando la version de Python 2.7.16... por lo que al escribir código de python3 me está dando muchos fallos al ejecutar
¿alguien sabe donde puede estar el fallo, o que estoy haciendo mal, o que estoy pasando por alto?

Uso macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 Y Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0)

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: En macOS puedes usar entornos virtuales "***virtualenv***", para poder cambiar entre versiones de python ya que si no me equivoco el SO utiliza la versión 2.7 para funcionar.

Comment: Puedes revisar [este post](https://rukbottoland.com/blog/tutorial-de-python-virtualenv/) para mas información

Comment: OK, gracias por responder. Intentaré crear un entorno virtual como indicas. Saludos